# How to hide image on click with two functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using simple image what I'm trying to do is on click of image it will do two things first is it will hide the image and play content in the back i'm using an iframe video which has no play button so once you were to click on anywhere of the video it plays so I'm trying to add simple play button where use will click on the image and video will play i need help with javascript any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="playbutton">
<img style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 0;" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg">

</div>
```

Comment: hey check out my answer below, it should hide the image, and send a click event to the video, just place the video id where it says

Comment: Do you have a `<video>` element in the `<iframe>`..? or is it something else..? how can we access it..?

Comment: its an iframe youtube is good example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check fiddle out @ *http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/4/*

Try this:

```
 JQuery:
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

  });
});

HTML:
<div id="playbutton">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRh0Aw8dopC_x6jfb8wYuiVRoo9Xy0EwWQskikB8MmE_AAepfUZEowIMQ" onclick="this.style.display='none';" id="play-video">

<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

CSS:
#play-video {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 0;
bottom: 10;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto; 
}
```

check fiddle out @ *http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/4/*
If you need more help or this is not what your looking for please comment back - i'm happy to help!

Comment: i update the original video on fiddle but when i added the code the only thing it does do is refresh but it doesn't play

Comment: @mia can you give me the url of the Video please

Comment: @mia simple problem try this --- http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/6/

Comment: @mia url should be this  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nYIr79YbvUg?rel=0" not this ...  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nYIr79YbvUg?"

Comment: i update it on fiddle

Comment: problem fixed @ http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/6/

Comment: @mia have you got it uploaded to youtube because google APIs take a heck of a long time

Comment: you have been really helpful  thank you for your help :))))))) you have made my day :)))))your awesome enjoy rest of your day

Comment: i will use youtube then thank for your advice :))))))

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciation - im  always happy to help. Also, could you please rate the question which helped you by voting it up so when others need advice from your post the most helpful answer is found at the top ,hence the one with the most votes.

Comment: i tried but it give me error saying "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" so far i have 10 but when i have 15 i will do so thanks :)))

Comment: @mia i think you have 15 now as i have voted your question

Comment: @mia i think you have 15 point REP now as i have voted your question. You can now vote the answers. Thanks

Comment: i need your help again how to show the button after the page is completely loaded?

Comment: thats ok. use the event onafterload="myfunctionhere()"

Comment: @mia Your welcome - I'm always happy to help with coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63372/discussion-between-mia-and-ip-address).

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
  <div id="playbutton">
  <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 0;" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-   content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg" onclick="this.style.display='none';PlayVideo();">

  </div>
```

so you add this onclick="this.style.display='none';PlayVideo();"

if you need more help, please reply

Comment: the tricked worked on hiding image but can the event do like two things once the image is hidden then javascript will do another click and the video will play?

Comment: it's good practice to keep your JS and HTML separate though, and from what it sounds like you want more functionality than what will fit in a single line

Comment: @michaelwayman you are right but the same could be said for styling

Comment: @mia please upload the code for the file you want to play and i am happy to help

Comment: i made http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/1/ using youtube video i couldn't add the css completely but that's sample of code i'm using on top is iframe video link and i will be adding css to the playbutton so it will fit perfect where it's suppose to and once the user click on the fake play button image then the video play since it will have two functions one to hide image other to play video thanks for helping:)

Comment: @mia use this website for playing the video http://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/

Comment: so the javascript can't like do two clicks when users click on the image first and then on the same spot the javascript will do another click to player video?

Comment: @mia hi im working on it - give me a minute. thanks

Comment: @mia Hi, i've done it. check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/4/

Comment: @mia if this is what your looking for please like my answer and mark it as answer. by the way i used jquery for the scripting